# How to see the problem raise by user which cannot simulate from our side

Tags: android, ios, xcode, debugging

My customer raise a problem about our app which is the app is getting slower when using for long time, but our side cannot simulate the problem as we are not in their real working environment, we are not able to solve the problem before knowing the bug. anyone can help?

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/perf-mon/

Answer (score 1):

If it´s a issue that raises "by the passing of time", you should look for any task you might be running and repeating itself.
You should check the different types of functionalities you use.
For example, if your app it´s using a local database:

- Look for unclosed cursors.
- I/O work

If your are using animations:

- Look for skipped frames
- Complex view hierarchies

If using background tasks or threading:

- I/O work
- Unfinished threads
- Increasing thread number

If  using networking and Webservices:

- Problems with your server database
- Connection issues
- Proxys
- ...

You could also use something like Firebase + Crashlytics to see if theres any warning raises but gets silently disposed.

Giving some more info about your app and what it does could be useful for elaborating more accurate solution.

Comment: Hi Axier, just give you the real scenrio... our customer always complain that our app is getting slow after few days/hours of using, our temporary solution for them is to kill the app. but this is not the good solution and we cant fix still and we already check our code many times.

Comment: What does the app do? HTTP calls, I/O, photos,...?

Answer (score 0):

A common source of slowing down apps is memory leaks.

on iOS what you can do is to activate `Memory management` flags on your target and keep a watch on the logs, you can also use Xcode Memory Graph and instruments leak tools to detect leaks.

on Android you can use tools like [LeakCanary](https://github.com/square/leakcanary) to be notified when leaks happens.

Once you have a leak detected you can inspect your code to identify the source and better manage memory.

Answer (score 0):

@axierjhtjz mention lots of good starting points.
Does it occur on both iOS and Android, specific devices, vendors?

If it is mainly on a single platform (Android/iOS), on different devices and the main complaint is slowness over time, I would suspect the following:

1. Memory leak (maybe UI, fragments)
2. Data persistent data incremental over time or/and more IO operation over time.

If you unable to debug the problem on the customer site, I would suggest to add a remote real time monitoring capabilities over relevant parameters and logs.

A good tool we used in the past was [TestFairy](https://www.testfairy.com/). maybe they have a free trial